# How can i calculate "pn" automatically?

Tags: python, numpy

i need some help to create a script to calculate the "pn" automatically.

Now I have this code:

```
import numpy as np
from itertools import product


a=np.arange(1,4,1) 
po= [] 
po = list(product(a, repeat =2))
array1= np.array(po)
array2= np.array([[2,40],[3,40],[4,43]])
p1=array1[0,0]*array2[:,1:]**array1[0,1] 
p2=array1[1,0]*array2[:,1:]**array1[1,1] 
p3=array1[2,0]*array2[:,1:]**array1[2,1]
```

`array1` represents the ordered pairs and the `array2` represents some values of depth.

The equation is `pn = array1(first element of pn line)*array2(the second column)**array1(second element of pn line)`

How can I solve that? How can I calculate all the `p` automatically?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Sorry. The value was incorrect

Comment: Yes. Sorry, was incorrect again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a variable, `n`, and use it where the array index needs to change. I put it in a function call for convenience and had to subtract 1 from n because arrays start at 0.

```
def calculate_pn(n):
    pn = array1[n-1,0]*array2[:,n-1:]**array1[n-1,1]
    return pn

> calculate_pn(n=1)
array([[40],
       [40],
       [43]], dtype=int32)
```

You can call this with a range of values to calculate multiple p values. Below I use a dict comprehension to make a lookup table of p values between 1 and the number of elements in array1.

```
> p = { n:calculate_pn(n) for n in range(1, len(array1)) }
> p[1]
array([[ 2, 40],
       [ 3, 40],
       [ 4, 43]], dtype=int32)
```

(You may wish to edit calculate_pn to accept array1 and array2 as parameters as well)

Comment: It is good solution but i need all the values automatically... For example: In this case the shape of array 1 is (9x2), i need all the 9 "p" automatically

Answer (score 1):

You could compute all the `pi` for `i = 1,...,n` all at once:

```
ps = (array1[:, 0] * (array2[:, 1:]**array1[:, 1])).T[..., None]
```

where

```
p1  equals ps[0], 
p2  equals ps[1], 
...

pn equals ps[n-1]
```

---

For example,

```
import numpy as np
from itertools import product

a = np.arange(1, 4, 1)
po = []
po = list(product(a, repeat=2))
array1 = np.array(po)
array2 = np.array([[2, 40], [3, 40], [4, 43]])
p1 = array1[0, 0] * array2[:, 1:]**array1[0, 1]
p2 = array1[1, 0] * array2[:, 1:]**array1[1, 1]
p3 = array1[2, 0] * array2[:, 1:]**array1[2, 1]

ps = (array1[:, 0] * (array2[:, 1:]**array1[:, 1])).T[..., None]

assert np.allclose(p1, ps[0])
assert np.allclose(p2, ps[1])
assert np.allclose(p3, ps[2])
```

---

This expression was found by considering the shapes of the component arrays.

```
In [294]: array2[:, 1:].shape
Out[294]: (3, 1)

In [295]: array1[:, 1].shape
Out[295]: (9,)
```

[Broadcasting](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) allows us to compute `(array2[:, 1:]**array1[:, 1])`, creating an array of shape (3, 9):

```
In [296]: (array2[:, 1:]**array1[:, 1]).shape
Out[296]: (3, 9)
```

Since `array1[:, 0]` is a 1D array of shape (9,):

```
In [297]: array1[:, 0].shape
Out[297]: (9,)
```

we can again use broadcasting to multiply the two together, resulting in an array of shape (3, 9):

```
In [299]: (array1[:, 0] * (array2[:, 1:]**array1[:, 1])).shape
Out[299]: (3, 9)
```

Since we want to `p1` to become `ps[0]`, and `p2` to become `ps[1]`, and so on,
we want the dimension of length `9` to be the first axis. So transpose:

```
In [300]: (array1[:, 0] * (array2[:, 1:]**array1[:, 1])).T.shape
Out[300]: (9, 3)
```

And since `p1` has shape `(3, 1)` instead of just `(3,)`, we need to add another dimension to the result. This is the purpose of indexing by `[..., None]`.

```
In [304]: (array1[:, 0] * (array2[:, 1:]**array1[:, 1])).T[..., None].shape
Out[304]: (9, 3, 1)
```